# flutter riverpod: how to test asyncvalue.error?

Tags: flutter, testing, widget, riverpod

I am having trouble testing my Riverpod FutureProvider when it returns an AsyncValue.error.

I tried the test as shown below:

```
// Future provider  
final ipsProvider = FutureProvider.autoDispose((_) =>  IpRepository().fetchIps());

// Widget to be tested
class ExampleWidget extends ConsumerWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, ScopedReader watch) {
    // hooks
    AsyncValue<List<Ip>> ips = watch(ipsProvider);
    return Container(
      child: ips.when(
        data: (data) => randomWidget,
        loading: () => progressIndicator,
        error: (_, stack) => Text('YesMan'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// Test: I am trying to find a Text widget containing message 'YesMan'
testWidgets('ExampleWidget | error', (WidgetTester tester) async 
  await tester.pumpWidget(
        ProviderScope(
            overrides: [
              ipsProvider.overrideWithValue(AsyncValue.error('randomErrorMessage')),
            ],
            child: MaterialApp(
              home: Builder(builder: (context) {
                return ExampleWidget();
              }),
            ),
          ),
      );
      final finderError = find.text('YesMan');
      expect(finderError, findsOneWidget);
    });
```

I expected the test to return a text widget with message 'randomError', but instead it throws an exception as below:

`══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FLUTTER TEST FRAMEWORK The following message was thrown running a test: randomErrorMessage When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:`

Any idea on how to test AsyncValue.error cases in Riverpod?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of `overrideWithValue` try `overrideProvider` and run a future.error so FutureProvider catch it

```
class ExampleWidget extends ConsumerWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, ScopedReader watch) {
    // hooks
    AsyncValue<String> ips = watch(ipsProvider);
    return Container(
      child: ips.when(
        data: (data) => SizedBox(),
        loading: () => CircularProgressIndicator(),
        error: (_, stack) => Text('YesMan'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

testWidgets('ExampleWidget | error', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    await tester.pumpWidget(
      ProviderScope(
        overrides: [
          ipsProvider.overrideWithProvider(FutureProvider((_) => Future.error('error'))),
        ],
        child: MaterialApp(
          home: Builder(builder: (context) {
            return ExampleWidget();
          }),
        ),
      ),
    );

    expect(find.byType(CircularProgressIndicator), findsOneWidget);

    await tester.pump();

    final finderError = find.text('YesMan');
    expect(finderError, findsOneWidget);
  });
```

Comment: @josharchibal please mark this as the accepted answer if it solved your issue.